# npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\gulp\node_modules\fsevents):

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to install GULP but im getting this warning or error

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\gulp\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ gulp@4.0.2
added 313 packages from 217 contributors and updated 1 package in 28.108s
```

The configuration is Node v10.16.3 | npm v- 6.12.0 | im working on 64 bit windows10

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the warning, that dependency is specific for Mac OS and you are on Windows so npm skips it, gulp will work anyway